# Error : 413 Request Entity Too Large in C# WinForm Application

Tags: c#, php, json, winforms

I am trying to send JSON Object to Server for data synchronization.
This JSON object contain non-synchronized images and their data.

Real problem is not with he JSON or the Synchronization code.
But it is with the size of the Request i am sending to the server.
if the size cross the limit 1.1MB then i Got this message

`The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large.`

Please Help me. It is pur C# application not the WCF application.
Domain Hosting provider is Godady.com.
Using Apache server and PHP script.

Every this is working fine for smaller size. but it give exception error when size cross 1.1MB.

Here is My Request Code.

```
public string SubmitData(string poststring)
    {
        string result ="false";

        if (poststring.ToLower() == "empty")
        {
            result = "empty";
            return result;
        }

        try
        {
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string postData = poststring;
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);


            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://blunor.com/dark/data.php");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            showMessageBox(data.Length.ToString(), "Message", 1);
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Close();

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);

            // this block of code check if response is +ve or negtive..
            string res_num = sr.ReadToEnd();

                if (res_num == "1")
                {
                    result = "true";
                }
                else
                {
                    result = "false";
                }
            //block end here.....

            sr.Close();
            stream.Close();

            return result;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

For Server php `post_max_size = 128M` and `Upload_max_filesize = 32M`

Please Help......

Comment: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/413-request-entity-too-large-error-with-uploading-a-file

Comment: Check this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

Comment: @PaulBain i have check that link. But I am not able to find httpd.conf file on godady.com server. can you help